# SQL Stored Procedure for using IN clause with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

If you have two table Employee and Department.

- tblEmp - EmpID, EmpName,DeptID are the fields
- tblDepartment - DeptID,DeptName are the fields

Employee and Department table have the foreign key relation.

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmp e
INNER JOIN tblDepartment d on d.DeptID = e.DeptID
WHERE d.DeptID IN ('1','2')
```

How to write stored procedure for above statement?
The department id values in where clause `IN` statement are dynamic (1,2) or (1,2,3) what ever I will pass them dynamically.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that other than passing the multiple values in as a single delimited string and then breaking it up in the SQL code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - There are other options, but they're all *(imo)* quite clunky too.  For example, table valued parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass all values in single varchar(max) object.

Then in your sp, you can split your values by using split function and then put 'IN' clause on it.

```
Create procedure sp_test
@var1 nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    select * from tblEmp e
    Inner join tblDepartment d on d.DeptID = e.DeptID
    where d.DeptID IN select value from dbo.split(@var1))
end
```

Comment: You should put the code for that `split` too, to make a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

create a function to split the comma separated values as below,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
Id int identity(1,1),
Value nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN
   While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
   Begin 
       Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
       Select
       Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
       Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
   End 

   Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
   Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
   Return
END
```

In your Stored Procedure call the function as below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_getvalues
@var1 nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM tblEmp e
    INNER JOIN tblDepartment d 
    on d.DeptID = e.DeptID
    WHERE d.DeptID IN (SELECT value FROM [dbo].[FnSplit](@var1))

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```